# UNNotificationAction not showing in remote notification

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am implemetaing actionable remote notification but action button are not showing while `notification` come.

**Payload**

> {"aps":{"alert":"Testing..
>   (11)","badge":1,"sound":"default"},"category":"newnote"}

**My Code**

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        self.configureUserNotifications()
        self.registerForRemoteNotification()

        return true
    }


func registerForRemoteNotification() {
    let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
    if error == nil{
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}


func configureUserNotifications() {
        let acceptAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier:
            "accept", title: "✅ Accept note", options: [])
        let rejectAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier:
            "reject", title: "❌ Reject note", options: [])
        let category =
            UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "newnote",
                                   actions: [acceptAction,rejectAction],
                                   intentIdentifiers: [],
                                   options: [])

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            .setNotificationCategories([category])
    }



    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Registration for remote notifications failed")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("Registered with device token: \(deviceToken.hexString)")
        self.deviceToken = deviceToken.hexString
    }


    //Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("User Info = ",notification.request.content.userInfo)
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    //Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("User Info = ",response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
        print("Response received for \(response.actionIdentifier)")

        if response.actionIdentifier == "accept" {

        }
        else if response.actionIdentifier == "reject" {

        }
        completionHandler()
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling [`setNotificationCategories‍‍‍`](https://www.google.com/search?q=setNotificationCategories&oq=setNotificationCategories&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0j69i60j0l2.417j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) once across your entire app? When ever you call it, it **replaces** previous categories. So upon registration you should have ALL your categories ready

Comment: This does not apply to the code sample above, maybe this will help somebody - make sure you only call UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories() with all your categories in a single array once.  If you call it multiple times with different categories, everything seems to work fine, but custom actions never seem to be presented.  The comment above helped me fix my issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think if you move `UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            .setNotificationCategories([category])` to your `registerForRemoteNotification` function, the problem will resolve. Something like this:

```
 if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: Set([category]))
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
```

Comment: Not entirely sure why that worked, but it did. Thanks.